# How can i create uint40 in python?

Tags: web3.py, python

I need to create a uint40 number for sign message.

```
random_hex = hex(random.getrandbits(256))
reveal = int(random_hex, base=16)
commit_hash = w3.toHex(w3.sha3(encode_single('uint256', reveal)))
commit = int(commit_hash, base=16)
```

and i need from commit and last block number create a uint40 number. In js it is:

```
const result = '0x'+ web3.eth.abi.encodeParameter('uint256', lastBlock).split('x')[1].split('').reverse().slice(0,10).reverse().join('') + web3.eth.abi.encodeParameter("uint256", commit).split("x")[1];
```

How i can create the same in python?